# Clear all cookies from a Titanium webview on android

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, webview, titanium-mobile

I want to delete all cookies from a `webview` in an Alloy application.

I have found different solutions from other questions but none worked.

I have tried:

```
Ti.Network.createHTTPClient().clearCookies(MY_URL);

Ti.Network.removeHTTPCookiesForDomain(MY_URL);

var cookiesPath = Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory+'/Library/Cookies';
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(cookiesPath);
if(file.exists()) file.deleteDirectory(true);

$.webview.evalJS('(function (){'+
        'var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");' +
        'for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {' +
        '   var cookie = cookies[i];' +
        '   var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");' +
        '   var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;' +
        '   document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";' +
        '}})();');
```

Comment: Remove help request and fixed grammar. Better to add more details to the question to get answers faster